# Updating table with the data from another unrelated table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have the following tables:
`client(id,country,name)` and `temp(id,country)`, and they are UNRELATED between each other.
I want to know how can I set the temp.id value to client.id, and same with the country. Is it with an update sentence? I've been looking at other web sites and I just found solutions for related tables, and that's not my case.

Comment: it's unclear. what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: If they are not related, why is client-id related to temp-id?

Comment: @rudym Sorry, I'm working with a bigger database but the table I need to modify is the client one, with the temp data. What I need to do is the following: "Create a temporal table that picks clients from Spain. Update their id, adding 10 and changing the country to Germany. Insert on the client table these modified clients". I've already done the first steps (creating the table and updating its data), but I'm stuck in the part where I have to add the modified clients from the temporal table to the client table.

Comment: Sounds like you should do insert at the end, not update.

Comment: @rudym Oh my god. I misread the sentence. Didn't know it was inserting back, I thought it was updating. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a simple `insert`:

```
insert into client
select id, country, '' from temp
```

You may want to set a specific `name` because it's not in the `temp` table (unless it's nullable in `client` table).

[Here is a demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1ddc/1).

Alternatively, if `id` is an auto incremented column, remove the `id` from the `select`:

```
insert into client
select country, '' from temp
```

[Here is a demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3ffa/1).

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking procedurally when you should think in SETs.

Retrieve the data using SELECT
Choose only clients from Spain using WHERE
Modify the data as part of retrieval using constant values for columns
Use the retrieved data to insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO client
SELECT id+10 as id, 'Germany' as country
FROM client
WHERE country = 'Spain'
```

Of course, if this is an exercise where you have to learn things like SELECT, WHERE, UPDATE etc, then you'd do your procedural steps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to synchronize both tables, one way:

```
UPDATE t SET t.id=c.id, t.country=c.countryname
FROM client c INNER JOIN temp t ON t.id = c.id

INSERT INTO temp(id,country)
  SELECT c.id, c.countryname
  FROM client c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM temp t 
                   WHERE t.id=c.id)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a41de/4/1)